# What df.index.freq do I have to set for two hourly data?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, frequency

When doing Time series Analysis we need to set a frequency like this for monthly data:

```
df.index.freq = 'MS'
```

What frequency do I have to set if I have two hourly data (or 30 days data etc.)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) if need change frequency:

```
df = df.asfreq('2H')
```

If need data processing - e.g. aggregate by `sum` per 2 hours, 30 days:

```
df1 = df.resample('2H').sum()

df2 = df.resample('30D').sum()
```

Comment: Thank you! One question. Why do we have to set the frequency when analyzing time series? Note: I do not have any missing values.

Comment: @Tobitor - Hard question, I think because pandas best working with consecutive timeseries, so after `resample` or asfreq got it, also are created NaNs rows if some value misisng.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But then it is not mandatory in my case?

Comment: @Tobitor - Hard question, but obviously not necessary (because some functions like `resample` do it)